# XCode 4.6 crash report stacktrace only

Tags: debugging, ios6, xcode4.6, nsexception, crash-log

A customer send me this crash log, it only contains the stack trace. This stack trace is generated by a custom developed exception handler.

```
Exception message:
NSInvalidArgumentException

Exception Reason:
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: pop_year)

Stacktrace:

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x3a9dc3ff <redacted> + 186
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39a35963 objc_exception_throw + 30
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3a93e5ef <redacted> + 142
3   SimplyStats                         0x0004640b SimplyStats + 103435
4   SimplyStats                         0x000458e1 SimplyStats + 100577
5   SimplyStats                         0x00034b83 SimplyStats + 31619
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x337c4793 <redacted> + 10
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x337c7b3b <redacted> + 142
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x337c567d <redacted> + 44
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x337c8613 <redacted> + 210
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x337c87d9 <redacted> + 92
11  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33cb67f1 <redacted> + 360
12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x33cb6684 start_wqthread + 8
)
```

This question has two parts:

1. Can I symbolicate this partial crash log? (Yes I have the .app and .dsym of the actual file).
2. What must I change in my exception handler to be able to import the crash log properly for future crash events?

EDIT: A little more info; i managed to get a decoding of the hex values by using

```
atos -o SimplyStats.app/SimplyStats -arch armv7 0x00034b83
```

I did the same for some more hexadecimal numbers. But it's rather tedious! I am sure there must be a smarter way.

**EDIT 2: Since my question gets no answers, is what would be a best practice for logging `NSExceptions` and Stacktraces in an email message so they can be properly analyzed?**

Comment: Wonder if this helps?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: Thanks for the referrals, but i read most of them already...